# Write referenced GeoTiff with 4 corners on matlab

Tags: geotiff-tiff, matlab, matlab-mapping-toolbox

I have some matlab raster matrix to export to geotif.
I also have the location of each corner in Decimal degrees (WGS84).
I know how to export and write the data into a geotiff but i'm having a problem to use the 4 corners for geolocation.
The raster is a strip map and it's not oriented to the north (it's slanted).

I can georefrence it afterwards on arcmap but i'm trying to avoid it and add it to the matlab script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it code but your image should be parallel with meridian.

`filename` is your image. You should have longitude and latitude of upper left & lower right.

```
DX = (lonmax-lonmin)/(length(filename(1,:)));
DY = (latmin-latmax)/(length ...(filename(:,1)));
% % lonmin, latmax both of them are center of pixel(1,1)
Reference = makerefmat(lonmin+(0.5*DX), latmax-(0.5*DY), DX, DY);
%% reference name with filename Both should have a name 
fn=[reference name, '.tfw' ];
worldfilewrite(Reference ,fn);
```